# Combining solutions while solving

Tags: equation-solving

Here is a simple representation of my problem.

I want to solve

```
Solve[(w^2*c^2 /. #) - 1 == 0, w]& /@ {{c -> 1}, {c -> 2}}
```

> ```
> {{{w -> -1}, {w -> 1}}, {{w -> -(1/2)}, {w -> 1/2}}}
> ```

The thing is, I want to combine this with value of `c` like this

> ```
> {{c->1, w->-1}, {c->1,w->1}, {c->2,w->-1/2}, {c->2,w->1/2}}
> ```

I used

```
Outer[Union, #, Solve[(w^2*c^2 /. #) - 1 == 0, w]] & /@ {{c -> 1}, {c -> 2}}
```

for this but it gives

> Rule::argrx: Rule called with 4 arguments; 2 arguments are expected. >>.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to do this ?

Note:The example which I gave is simple but my problem is generic. So instead of  `w^2*c^2 == 0` there can be any equation which can give any number of solutions.

Answer (score 6):

I like this short one:

```
Solve[w^2 c^2 - 1 == 0 && (c == 1 || c == 2), {w, c}]
(*{{w -> -1, c -> 1}, {w -> 1, c -> 1}, {w -> -(1/2), c -> 2}, {w -> 1/2, c -> 2}}*)
```

It can be generalized as:

```
cvalues = {1, 2, 5, 6};
Solve[w^2 c^2 - 1 == 0 && Or @@ Thread[c == cvalues], {w, c}]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ArrayReshape[Tuples /@ ({#, Solve[(w^2*c^2 /. #)-1 == 0, w]} & /@ {{c -> 1}, {c -> 2}}), {4, 2}]
```

or

```
Partition[Flatten[Tuples /@ ({#,Solve[(w^2*c^2 /. #)-1 == 0, w]} & /@ {{c -> 1}, {c -> 2}})], 2]
```

both give

```
(* {{c -> 1, w -> -1}, {c -> 1, w -> 1}, {c -> 2, w -> -(1/2)}, {c -> 2, w -> 1/2}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
cc = {c -> 1, c -> 2};

sol = Solve[(w^2*c^2 /. #) - 1 == 0, w] & /@ cc;

Partition[Riffle[Riffle[cc, cc], Flatten @ sol], 2]
```

[image]

```
cc = {c -> 1, c -> 2, c -> 3};

sol = Solve[(w^2*c^2 /. #) - 1 == 0, w] & /@ cc;

Partition[Riffle[Riffle[cc, cc], Flatten @ sol], 2]
```

[image]

Comment: `riffle = {c -> 1, c -> 2}; ....; Partition[
 Riffle[Riffle[riffle, riffle], Flatten@sol], 2]`

Comment: @belisarius lol

Answer (score 2):

```
sol = Flatten[Solve[{w^2*c^2 - 1 == 0, c == #}, {c, w}] & /@ {1, 2}, 1]
```

> {{c -> 1, w -> -1}, {c -> 1, w -> 1}, {c -> 2, w -> -(1/2)}, {c -> 2, 
>   w -> 1/2}}

```
sol == Flatten[
  Solve[{w^2*c^2 - 1 == 0, c == #}, {c, 
      w}] & /@ (c /. {{c -> 1}, {c -> 2}}), 1]
```

> True